# Hiding of dynamic button with Swift3

Tags: swift3, uibutton

I want to hide a dynamic button with Swift 3 but I can't get it done. I just started with Swift but have some time pressure considering development of an app.

After pressing ButtonGen1 I want to hide this button and view 2 other buttons namely ButtonGen2_1 and ButtonGen2_2.

Using Google I tried several things. For example the following:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    createButtonGen1()
    buttonGen1?.removeFromSuperview
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func createButtonGen1 ()
{
    let buttonGen1 = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x:100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 50))
    buttonGen1.setTitle("Is the original visit to this outlet to Eat or Drink?", for: .normal)
    buttonGen1.setTitleColor(UIColor.orange, for: .normal)
    buttonGen1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonActionGen1), for: .touchUpInside)
    self.view.addSubview(buttonGen1)
}

func createButtonGen2_1 ()
{
    let buttonGen2_1 = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x:50, y: 100, width: 100, height: 150))
    buttonGen2_1.setTitle("Is the name Restaurant?", for: .normal)
    buttonGen2_1.setTitleColor(UIColor.blue, for: .normal)
    buttonGen2_1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction2_1), for: .touchUpInside)
    self.view.addSubview(buttonGen2_1)
}

func createButtonGen2_2 ()
{
    let buttonGen2_2 = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x:150, y: 100, width: 100, height: 150))
    buttonGen2_2.setTitle("Is the name Restaurant?", for: .normal)
    buttonGen2_2.setTitleColor(UIColor.red, for: .normal)
    buttonGen2_2.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction2_2), for: .touchUpInside)
    self.view.addSubview(buttonGen2_2)
}

func buttonActionGen1(sender: UIButton!) {
// ----> HOW TO HIDE BUTTON buttonGen1 
    buttonGen1.hidden = true
    createButtonGen2_1 ()
    createButtonGen2_2 ()
}

func buttonAction2_1(sender: UIButton!)
{
    print("Button 2_1 tapped")
}

func buttonAction2_2(sender: UIButton!)
{
    print("Button 2_2 tapped")
}
```

HOW TO HIDE BUTTON buttonGen1 ?!?!?!?

Your help is much appreciated!!!

Comment: Define buttonGen1 outside of the functions. You cant access from another function scope unless you pass as parameter.

Comment: A little bit late but thanks! The app is ready!